# Can I create alias for partial class name?

Tags: c#

i.e. I have

```
namespace newProject{


     public partial class Default_Animal {

        protected int Amount = 5;

        .....
     }
     .....
}
```

I have the default (hundreds) of properties and fields. I want to use it in second class like, to extend it :

```
using Dog = newProject.Default_Animal;  //<--- this is example to show What i want to achieve

namespace newProject{

       public partial class Dog : WildAnimal_X {

           Print(Amount);      //<--- doesn't seem to work

       } 
}
```

Comment: You're naming convention is wanting...

Comment: It's my understanding that you can't split a partial class across different namespaces.

Comment: Looking at the [Partial types section of the C# Specifications](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/master/spec/classes.md#partial-types) you'll see that partial types are required to `have the same name and be declared in the same namespace or type declaration as the other parts`

Comment: @T.Todua Again, did you read? The answer is **no**, no matter how often you keep asking!

Comment: Your are not following the proper conventions for naming, e.g. your classes.  You should name classes with upper camel case, not with underscores.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/names-of-classes-structs-and-interfaces

Comment: WildAnimal_X is not even defined.

Comment: It was not an answer, it was a comment @T.Todua. And I think that pointing to the documentation that clearly states it is not possible is useful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you can't alias the name of a class in its declaration. You also can't define the other part of the partial class in another namespace: the namespace, class name and parent type should all match.

Allowing this is not useful in any way. It opens up for confusion, as in this example. `Dog` should be deriving from `Animal`, and it should not be a `partial class` with `Animal`.

This is what you should have:

```
public class Dog : Animal /* drop Default_ */
{
}
```

Comment: let say, they are in same namespace, with different class names. can I alias?